# Desired Unique ID Field not showing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, unique-id

[image]

I am trying to do an ordinary least squares on some data, and the value field for the 'Unique ID Field' that I want to select isn't appearing, so I'm not able to run my ols.
Has anyone encountered this problem, and managed to overcome it?

Comment: check your field data type. It appears it needs to be an integer, perhaps a short vs long type issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your screen shot in the help panel is clearly states an INTEGER field is required. I suspect your ID field is not of this format, may be it is a string or decimal? You would need to create a unique ID field of type LONG.